# mysql connect all fields in two columns

Tags: if-statement, mysql-workbench, self-join

I have a view with two columns: a person's ID (a number) and the sector that they below to (given as numbers 1-5).

I want to create a view to show whether people belong to the same sector. I think this would have three columns: ID1, ID2, and SameSector. The first column would list IDs, and for each ID in column 1 the second column would list ALL of the IDs. The third column would be an if statement, 1 if the sector was the same for both IDs, 0 if it wasn't. This is made slightly more complicated because a person can belong to more than one sector.

For example:

I have:

```
ID Sector

1    1
2    1
2    5
3    1
```

I want:

```
ID1 ID2 SameSector
1    1     1
1    2     1
1    2     0
1    3     0
2    1     1
2    1     0
```

etc.

I'm guessing this involves some sort of self join and if statement but I can't figure out how to get all of the ID fields to be listed in ID1 column and matched to all of the ID fields in ID2 any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you want:

```
SELECT a.ID AS ID1, b.ID AS ID2, IF(a.Sector=b.Sector,1,0) AS SameSector
FROM theTable AS a, theTable AS b
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2cbc/4

I initially had a much more complicated query, but then realized you wanted a complete cross-join, including the same ID comparing to itself.